# telerik control in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, telerik, xamarin.forms

I am trying to Use telerik control in my Xamarin cross paltform app.For that i have downloaded and installed telerik_ut_for_xamarin.

and i have added references in perticular project.

now i am trying to use listview in  sipmle xaml page from this [article](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/listview/listview-getting-started)  but i m getting this error

```
The type or namespace name 'Telerik' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

so what i am missing here.. i read on some sites that i should reference namespace on xaml page on which i m trying to use control..but which namespace?

can anyone please help me i. i m new to xamarin as well as telerik too..any good doucument or article?or sample code if anyone have tried this please help me

Answer (score 2):

The namespace you need is:
`xmlns:telerikDataControls="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls"` and you add that into the definition of your page. I took that from [Telerik's example in the article you listed](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/listview/listview-getting-started#example) (if you're wondering).

Here's an example of a `ContentPage` using that namespace and `RadListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="XamarinCRM.Pages.MenuPage"
    xmlns:telerikDataControls="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls"
>
     <ContentPage.Content>
          <telerikDataControls:RadListView x:Name="LV"/> 
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: i added that namespace allready.though i was getting eror.and intelerik folder there is no such path like in namespace. so i was asking should i add another namespac? and which one?

Comment: Are the Telerik DLLs installed in your C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for Xamarin QX XXX\Binaries directory? If not, I would guess something went wrong with your installation.

Comment: oh..it is working now.. i just missed to add assembly reference in mainActivity.cs file..ny silly mistake

Comment: @dylanstrug : thank you for your time.can you suggest me some samples from i can check how to use fetures of controls like how can i use listview as gridview etc.. any good sample  or link that can u suggest me .pls

Comment: I'm glad to hear you got it working. I've never used Telerik's controls, so I don't know any good references. Sorry. Best of luck though!